# How are nuxt-community/starter-template and create-nuxt-app related?

Tags: nuxt.js

[Nuxt guide](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation/#using-nuxt-js-starter-template) recommends to use [nuxt-community/starter-template](https://github.com/nuxt-community/starter-template), while [npm package description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt) first of all suggests [nuxt-community/create-nuxt-app](https://github.com/nuxt-community/create-nuxt-app). What tool should be used? Is `create-nuxt-app` the replacement of all `*-template`s?

Answer (score 1):

> Nuxt guide recommends to use nuxt-community/starter-template

yes! To guide the first time users of nuxt using their template.

The templates consists of directory structure (with readme.md), basic nuxt.config.js to get started

> npm package description first of all suggests nuxt-community/create-nuxt-app.

nuxt-community/create-nuxt-app is a generator (like yeoman generator) for setting up your project by choosing framework (from the listed) for UI and Server.

In simple words, nuxt-community/create-nuxt-app is to help you set up nuxt setup with frameworks installed with default configurations